# super respondsToSelector: returns true but actually calling super (selector) gives "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uigesturerecognizer, super, respondstoselector

OK, I am a little confused.

I have a subclass of UIScrollView, which is my attempt at a horizontally scrolling "table view" like UI element.  UIScrollView itself sets up UIGestureRecognizers it uses internally, and it appears to set itself up as the delegate for those UIGestureRecognizers.  I also have my own UIGestureRecognizer setup on my horizontal table elements/cells and my own class set as delegate for my own UIGestureRecognizer.  Since my class is a subclass of UIScrollView, at runtime, the UIGestureRecognizer delegate calls come to my class for both the UIScrollView in-built UIGestureRecognizers and my own UIGestureRecognizers.  A bit of a PITA but we can work around this by passing on the ones we don't care about.

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{ 
   if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
      return NO; 
      else
      {  
        if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)])
           return [super gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer];
           else 
           return NO;
        }
}
```

The problem is that the check `[super respondsToSelector:@selector()]` returns YES, but when I then actually call it `return [super gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer];` I get the following exception

> 2012-08-31 12:02:06.156 MyApp[35875:707] -[MyAppHorizontalImageScroller gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21dd50

I would have thought that it should show

> -[UIScrollView gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:]

But that may be OK.  But the problem is that it says that it responds and then doesn't.

The other two UIGestureRecognizer delegate routines work with this code (different selectors obviously).

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unless you override responds to selector in your class you will be using the default implementation when you call super which will check the current instance. If you want to see if a instance of a type of object responds to a selector use `+(BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector;`

This will check the object and its parent objects. So in your case you want to the following:

```
[UIScrollView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)]
```

Comment: Thanks.  The Apple Ref for this is http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:

Comment: As an aside, strangely enough, UIScrollView returns true for some of the UIGestureRecognizer delegate methods but not all.  I guess the default is good enough for it.   Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

`[super respondsToSelector:@selector(frobnosticate:)]` doesn't do what you think.

It goes to the superclass, gets the implementation of `respondsToSelector:` there, and then runs it *on the current object*. In other words, `super` represents the same object as `self`, it just starts the method lookup one step higher in the inheritance tree.

So you're running `respondsToSelector:` on this subclass, which replies "YES", but then later trying to get `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` from the superclass, which doesn't have it.

To check instances of the immediate superclass, you would use `instancesRespondToSelector:`, as jjburka recommend, but I would suggest `[self superclass]` as the subject of that, like so:

```
[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)];
```

which avoids hardcoding class names.

Comment: Apple recommends against [[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector as mentioned here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:

Comment: It's there under -respondsToSelector where it says "You cannot simply use `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]` since this may cause the method to fail if it is invoked by a subclass."

Comment: I must be missing something, because I can't see how a subclass's superclass can not have an implementation of a method if that class's superclass has it.

Comment: If you subclass it again.  The subclass calls its superclass which is still a subclass of the original.  If I have MyScrollView which is a subclass of UIScrollView, and then I have MyOtherScrollView which is a subclass of MyScrollView, when you are in MyOtherScrollView, `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aSelector)]` is not the same as `[UIScrollView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aSelector)]`

Comment: I understand they're not the same, but MyOtherScrollView and MyScrollView instances will respond to aSelector via inheritance and by doing [super aSelector] in MyOtherScrollView uses MyScrollView'a implementation anyways.

Comment: But the whole reason to test is to see if the base class responds to the selector.  In the example I gave, `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aSelector)]` won't answer that for my hypothetical MyOtherScrollView.  Apple's Docs discourage it for that case since it does not return the right info those who need to know that.

Comment: But you're not getting the base class's implementation if you use `[` ***`super`*** `gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer];` in `MyOtherScrollView` -- you're getting `MyScrollView`'s. You're asking the base class if it responds, and then using the middle subclass's implementation.

Comment: I don't disagree in my particular case.  My mention of the Apple recommendations was for general problems of this nature.  They recommend against it and give the reason, IIRC, to have to do with further superclasses.  Anyway, thanks for your insight into the issue!

Comment: @JoshCaswell: What he's saying is, if `self`'s class is `MyOtherScrollView`, and you are in an instance method of `MyScrollView`, and you run `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aSelector)]`, it will test whether `MyScrollView` responds to `aSelector`, and not whether `UIScrollView` responds to `aSelector`. So, in that same method of `MyScrollView`, even if the above expression returns true, `[super aSelector]` may still fail, because `UIScrollView` might not respond to that selector.

Comment: It seems my own understanding of `super` was faulty, @newacct. I thought `[super aSelector];` in `MyScrollView` would become -- in effect -- `struct objc_super sup = {self, [self superclass]}; ((void (*)(struct objc_super *, SEL))objc_msgSendSuper)(&sup, @selector(aSelector));`, but then that leads to an infinite loop when `self` is a `MyOtherScrollView` instance, of course.

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the other answers, the best solution is to use `[[MapControllerSublcass1 superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd]`. If you use what is recommended above, something like `[BaseClass instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd]`, you run into the problem of changing your class hierarchy and accidentally forgetting to change `BaseClass` to the new superclass or your subclass.

`[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:...]` is incorrect as explained above in the comments and it actually says so on [Apple's documentation (See respondsToSelector: in NSObjct)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector). It only works when you have 1 level of subclassing, so it gives you the ***illusion*** that it is an actual solution. I fell for it.

And `[[super class] instancesRespondToSelector:...]` doesn't work and is the whole point of this SO question.

For example, I have a `BaseMapController` that implements some of the methods in `MKMapViewDelegate`, but it doesn't implement `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`. `MapControllerSublcass1` inherits from `BaseMapController`. And `MapControllerSubclass2` inherits from `MapControllerSublcass1`.

In my code I have something like this, and it works fine.

***MapControllerSublcass1.m***:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
  if ([[MapControllerSublcass1 superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd]) {
    [super mapView:mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:animated];
  }
}
```

***MapControllerSubclass2.m***:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
  if ([[MapControllerSubclass2 superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd]) {
    [super mapView:mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:animated];
  }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `[MapControllerSubclass2 superclass]` with `[self superclass]`.

Comment: No, you should not. See the second paragraph above.

Comment: Using `super` is not necessarily an 'illusion' per se. Apple has noted this in the [NSObject Protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:). Since the protocol doesn't abstract above `self`, `super` *is* essentially `self`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
[super respondsToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)]
```

This is going to the superclass and running its implementation of `respondsToSelector`. This looks at the instance (in this case your custom scroll view) and determines if it responds to that selector or not.

When you call

```
[super gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer];
```

You try to send a message using the superclass implementation of that method, which in this case does not exist, causing the crash.

Looks like jjburka got to it first - you need to call

```
[UIScrollView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)]
```

Also, it won't crash if you use `-[super performSelector:]` from unrecognized selector - perform selector gets the instances implementation of the selector. It will crash from infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

As a summary for someone with the same case, there are two problems in the original question:

1. Checking whether the superclass responds to that selector, which as suggested by @jjburka is best done by using `instancesRespondToSelector:`.
2. Actually invoking the method on the superclass without the compiler complaining even though it's declared in a private header. This can be neatly achieved by redeclaring it in a category (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678463)).

Putting it together this gives:

```
// … In subclass implementation file
@interface UIScrollView () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> @end

// … In gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
if ([UIScrollView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)]) {
    return [super gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer];
}
```