# How to call superclass's protocol function?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, protocols

In my UITableViewController subclass, I overrode scrollViewDidScroll. I want to call parent class's scrollViewDidSroll also, in case it needs to run something. I get an unrecognized selector error when doing so. How is that possible if I check that it responds to the selector?

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)]) {
    // unrecognized selector
    [super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
  }
  // My child class's specific stuff
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220652/super-respondstoselector-returns-true-but-actually-calling-super-selector-giv) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test whether an object inherits a method from its superclass by sending `respondsToSelector:` to the object using the `super` keyword. This method will still be testing the object as a whole, not just the superclass’s implementation. Therefore, sending `respondsToSelector:` to `super` is equivalent to sending it to self. Instead, you must invoke the `NSObject` class method `instancesRespondToSelector:` directly on the object’s superclass, as illustrated in the following code fragment.

```
if( [MySuperclass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] ) {
    // invoke the inherited method
    [super aMethod];
}
```

You cannot simply use `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]` since this may cause the method to fail if it is invoked by a subclass.

Note that if the receiver is able to forward `aSelector` messages to another object, it will be able to respond to the message, albeit indirectly, even though this method returns `NO`.